# how to deal with the error of download package 'dplyr' in R

Tags: r, installation, dplyr

I have a problem install the package 'dplyr'. there is the error message:

```
library(dplyr)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘lifecycle’ 0.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.0 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.5.3```

I have tried to install the package 'lifecycle'. but the error still not fixed.

```
install.packages("lifecycle", dependencies = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘lifecycle’ 0.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.0 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.5.3```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Best wishes,
Ruozhu

Comment: First, install `lifecycle` by using `install.packages("lifecycle", dependencies = T)`, then install `dplyr` using `install.packages("lifecycle", dependencies = T)`.

Comment: thank you. be more precies. you mean install dplyr using install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = T)?@BappaDas

Comment: I would uninstall both packages first. Then Install dplyr then install lifecycle.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I have upgrade the newest version of R. then the problem has been solved.